# How to use notepad++ as external editor for 7zip

Tags: notepad++, 7zip

When using 7zip, clicking "edit" on a file inside of an archive, per default opens up notepad. How to use notepad++ instead?

7zip has the option to configure an external exitor.
Simply using the notepad++ exe does not work. Edit fails in notepad++ with an error message similar to "file cannot be saved, because it's already opened in another program" (I don't have an english installation).

Comment: Even if you want to edit some source code, this question is itself not programming-related.

Comment: Thank you. How can I move it to another StackExchange area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution: Use a batch script to wrap the command line arguments inside and link that batch script in 7zip.

Batch file content:

```
call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin %*
```

Ideas used from following posts:

- [How to use Jedit as the external editor of 7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34921965)
- [Use Notepad++ as Git Bash editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30395402)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help anyone anymore, the above command by Robert can be used in
Tools > Options > Editor

in View and Editor

"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"  -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin "%*"

This will open a new notepad++ editor without any other session and tab bar,
after editing, close the editor , you will be prompted with

File "xyz.txt" was modified . Do you want to update it in the archive ?
click ok/cancel

Answer (score 0):

for me, the zip file contains the file with ext .log. It was opened by notepad. From windows, change the default application for the file type .log. -> choose notepad++.
then the open the log file inside 7zip. it is opened by notepad++